# Can I take a car timing chain kit into a flight as checked luggage?

Tags: luggage, regulations, airport-security

I am travelling from the United States to Venezuela.

May I take this [timing chain kit](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00YHZ47O4) into my checked baggage?.

[image]

I have tried to locate information, but it is not clear. Seems that in general you can take auto spare parts as long as there is no hazardous materials in them (how would I know?!?).

I am also concerned about the silicone included in the kit.

Comment: I don't know enough about car mechanics to say, but if these parts were coated in fuel residue or a flammable oil, they might be denied carriage for that reason. Otherwise I don't see a reason for problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, I see nothing at all in such a kit that would raise any objections in checked baggage. They might open it up and have a look but there's nothing dangerous there. Except the silicone sealant they're all inert parts and nothing is going to leak out. Only flammable adhesives (which silicone is not) are prohibited. Suggest leaving the silicone in the original packaging and inside an additional clear ziplock bag and/or wrap it with a dispensable towel.

Stuff that has been used and has lubricants or fuel residue on it might not be okay.

I'd be a bit worried about those gaskets surviving intact. They're usually supplied shrink-packaged to a thin cardboard carrier and if they get folded they may leak.